# Insert html tag between word that starts with @ symbol in ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

```
    link = "http://github.com/"
    message = "Hi @freedom and @cake please review my commit."

    expected = "Hi <a href='http://github.com/freedom'>@freedom</a> and <a href='http://github.com/cake'>@cake</a> please review my commit."
```

How can I achieve the `expected` string above using the `link` and `message` values?

So far I can extract the `username` without the `@` symbol into Array.

```
links = []
message.scan(/@\b[^@][a-z]*\b/).each{|x| links << x.sub('@','')}


2.1.5 :010 > links
 => ["freedom", "cake"]
```

But I don't have any idea on how to insert `link` plus `links` into the `message` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code that you can use:

```
puts "Hi @freedom and @cake please review my commit.".gsub(/@([a-z]+)/i, "<a href='http:\/\/github.com\/\\1'>@\\1<\/a>")
```

Output:

```
Hi <a href='http://github.com/freedom'>@freedom</a> and <a href='http://github.com/cake'>@cake</a> please review my commit.
```

[Tested on TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTzA1NEk0VlJxMEk).

You can fine-tune the regex to `/(?<=^|\s)@([a-z]+)/i` to only match `@something` after a space or at the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby but usually you can work with capture-groups and reference them in the substitution text like in [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pP7dZ0/1). So I changed the regex slightly:

```
@\b([^@][a-z]*)\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3NX8_woh33AQwL-8)

I would say your regex is needlessly complicated though, I would do [this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XarOfRS7KiV4rFLh) to do it simpler and also accept numbers and underscore in their username (not uncommon):

```
@(\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]